# Why do I get integers in array when adding np.random.normal() to each element?

Tags: python, numpy

When I run this code

```
import numpy as np

y = np.arange(1,11)
for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] = y[i] + np.random.normal()

print(y)
```

I get the output

```
[ 2  1  2  3  2  6  6  7 10 10]
```

Why do all numbers in `y` gets converted into integers? `np.random.normal()` clearly do return floats.

Comment: doing: `y+np.random.normal(size=(len(y),))` will implicitely cast your `y` array and the result will be a `float64` array. But numpy will use implicite casting only if we apply an operation with a differente dtype on the whole array.

Comment: @obchardon, `y[i] + np.random.normal()` casts to float as well.  It's the following element  assignment that converts that back to the `y.dtype`.  What you are suggesting makes a whole new float array which remains float with `y=...`, but not with `y[:]=...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is as the `y` array in your example implicitly gets set to `dtype=int`. Therefore, while doing `y[i] = y[i] + np.random.normal()`, it is equivalent to `int = int + float`; i.e. a `float` has to be type-casted into an `int` before storing it.

You can circumvent this issue by manually specifying the `dtype` while creating the `numpy` array.

```py
import numpy as np

y = np.arange(1, 11, dtype=float)
for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] = y[i] + np.random.normal()

print(y)
# Sample output: [ 2.16400377  1.5604771   2.69698066  4.17251939  4.13071869  5.99501597  7.06189783  7.69103035 10.51589948 10.31083259]
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying it out, it appears that y[] has a dtype of int32, and does not change this when elements are modified.